# C# linq Select from Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

How to get part of dictionary, which keys are true for some conditionals.
For example, I have a dictionary.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary["first"] = 1;
dictionary["firstOfSecond"] = 2;
dictionary["second"] = 3;
dictionary["first-and-second"] = 4;
```

I need part of this dictionary, which keys are started from "first". How to do it?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` instead.

Comment: really not getting this one "I need part of this dictionary, which keys are started from 'first'". Did you mean those with keys starting with 'first'? i mean 1,2 & 4?

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("first"));
```

or

```
var result = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("first"));
```

Comment: Not sure why the edit from @Lidaranis but IMO the 2 descriptions you had over each code fragment added to your answer in a positive way as the poster does not seem to familiar with Linq, Dictionaries, and/or comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("first", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

All keys that start with `first` but any casing there of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StartWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) method of string:

```
var result= dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.StartWith("first"));
```

[`StartWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload where you can pass the `StringComparison` you want to use, eg, the current culture or the invariant culture, word or ordinal sort rules, and be case-sensitive or case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary.Keys.Where(t => t.StartsWith("first")).ToList();